# Categorize sites in IIS manager

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

We're hosting >100 websites on a single IIS7 server, and adding about a dozen monthly. The problem is using the IIS manager - it displays all of the sites under the "Sites" node. The list is very long and difficult to navigate.
Is there a way to categorize/divide the list some how (hierarchically)? Preferably in a controllable way - by customer, by website type?
The MSSQL server management studio has the same issue with displaying many databases in a single list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be nice to have a "folders"-like feature which could help in organizing web sites, if you have hundreds of them on a single server. As far as I know there is no way to do that in IIS Manager.

At least IIS 7 manager allows you to filter (name) and group the items by status, ip address, protocol or port. That was not an option in Windows Server 2003.

My solution is to have a very strict naming convention. We include the type/category of the site, the customer's name and even the main host header in the name, in order to be able to sort the list and making it easy to find single websites.

I hope sombody at Microsoft is listening.